# How to read in one file and display content vertically and then read in another file and display content vertically in c++

Tags: c++

Hi I'm working on a program that reads in two files and i want to display the files content in their own columns for ex.

```
File1                File2
Time     data        Time    data
```

I'm not quit sure how to create columns as such, I already have the code to read in the files and perform the functions needed its the output I'm stumped on. If anyone has any suggestions or help that would be awesome. Thanks! PS. This is NOT Homework Related.

Comment: One possible way is not to think of writing one file and then going back and writing the other. Instead interleave them. Write the first row from the first file, then the first row from the second file. Then new line and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int readLines(const std::string& fileName1, const std::string& fileName2)
{
    string line1;
    string line2;
    ifstream file1 (fileName1.c_str());
    ifstream file2 (fileName2.c_str());
    if (file1.is_open() && file2.is_open())
    {
        cout << setw(20) << left << "File1" << "File2" << endl;
        bool done;
        done = file1.eof() && file2.eof();
        while (!done)
        {
            getline (file1, line1);
            getline (file2, line2);
            line1.erase(std::remove(line1.begin(), line1.end(), '\n'), line1.end());
            line2.erase(std::remove(line2.begin(), line2.end(), '\n'), line2.end());
            cout << setw(20) << left << (file1.eof() ? "" : line1) << (file2.eof() ? "" : line2) << endl;
            done = file1.eof() && file2.eof();
        }

        file1.close();
        file2.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open some file";
    }

    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    std::string fileName1("example1.txt");
    std::string fileName2("example2.txt");
    readLines(fileName1, fileName2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh this is more like what im looking for ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what tools you are planning to use...

You can use some version of "curses" (a library with console manipulation functions such as "go to this position", "print text in green", etc), and then just walk around the screen as you like.

Or you could just read the files into separate variables and then print from each file in a loop. This requires no special codding. Just use an array or vector for the files themselves and the data you read from them.

Something like this:

```
const int nfiles = 2;

const char *filenames[nfiles] = { "file1.txt", "file2.txt" };

ifstream files[nfiles];
for(int i = 0; i < nfiles; i++)
{
   if (!files[i].open(filenames[i]))
   {
      cerr << "Couldn't open file " << filenames[i] << endl;
      exit(1);
   }
}
bool done = false;
while(!done)
{
   int errs = 0; 
   std::string data[nfiles];
   for(int i = i < nfiles; i++)
   {
       if (!(files[i] >> data[i]))
       {
          errs++;
          data[i] = "No data";
       }
   }
   if (errs == nfiles)
   {
      done = true;
   }
   else
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < nfiles; i++)
      {
           ... display data here ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example to look at as I'm not quite sure i understand fully

Comment: Okay i understand that now thank you, but as for setting the files to display on their own in two separate columns how would i do that?